# PyScript - NameError: name 'function' is not defined -- then *.py is load with <py-script src="..."> (DJango)

Tags: python, html, django, pyscript

I have a Python script containing a plot calculation and a function definition:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pyscript import Element
import datetime

x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
display(fig, target="plot")


def current_time():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # Get paragraph element by id
    paragraph = Element("current-time")

    # Add current time to the paragraph element
    paragraph.write(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

which I want to load into the HTML using DJango expressions combined with the `py-script`:
`<py-script src="{% static 'py/script.py' %}"></py-script>`. I found that the script is loaded and executed but the function is not recognised by the HTML button. If move the function code directly into the HTML tag, it works. What is going wrong here?

### Function definition within external py script

```html
{% extends "proj/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css"/>
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<py-config type="toml">
    packages = ["numpy", "matplotlib"]
</py-config>
{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}
<div id="plot"></div>
<button py-click="current_time()" id="get-time" class="py-button">Get current time</button>
<p id="current-time"></p>
{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
<py-script src="{% static 'py/script.py' %}"></py-script>
{% endblock script %}
```

results to:
[image]

### Function definition within HTML tag

```html
{% extends "proj/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css"/>
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<py-config type="toml">
    packages = ["numpy", "matplotlib"]
</py-config>
{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}
<div id="plot"></div>
<button py-click="current_time()" id="get-time" class="py-button">Get current time</button>
<p id="current-time"></p>
<py-script>
import datetime
def current_time():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # Get paragraph element by id
    paragraph = Element("current-time")

    # Add current time to the paragraph element
    paragraph.write(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
</py-script>
{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
<py-script src="{% static 'py/script.py' %}"></py-script>
{% endblock script %}
```

results to:
[image]

### the base template:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>{{ title }}</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/proj.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/forms.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Block which is reserved for extensions of the head (e.g. stylesheets) -->
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>


<main class="d-flex flex-nowrap">

    {% include 'proj/navbar.html' %}

    <div class="b-example-divider b-example-vr"></div>

    <div class="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

</main>

<!-- Block which is reserved for extensions of scripts -->
{% block script %}{% endblock %}

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working fine for me from the external file. Could you check the browser console for errors? Where is the `script` block in your main template?

Comment: @Dauros I added the template to the post

Comment: Would it be possible to copy the source (as in `view source`) of the page as rendered? I tried to get django set up to render all these templates/views to help, but failed. It might be easier to diagnose the issue with the page as-rendered.